# Facebook embedded "JOIN GROUP" button event .. something like Onclick

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have added join group fb plugin to my webpage, now i want to trigger a event when someone click on that "join group button".

FB.Event.subcribe is not working for this. i think that's only for like button

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '*********',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v3.3'
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  alert("working");
 });
};
   (function(d, s, id){
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

//code which I get from facebook

<div class="fb-group" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/[group-id]/" data-width="450" data-show-social-context="true" data-show-metadata="false"></div>
```

Comment: what makes you think that this is possible? did you check out the docs?

Comment: it is possible for like button. not sure for join.

Comment: No, it is not possible any more for the like button, that possibility was removed a good while back already. There is no way to do this using the SDK; and any “tricks” trying to achieve it would possibly be considered click-jacking attempts, so that is not advisable to begin with.

Comment: (It _could_ work with the code version to use in emails, because that is all static content embedded directly into your HTML, so you could attach your own event handlers to it - but using this on the web is explicitly not allowed, the documentation says _“Do not use this code in a web page.”_ in bold text in a warning box …)